# How can I select `array_agg` in `typeorm` with `postgresql`?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am using `typeorm` in typescript project to connect to `postresql 11`.
I have below query in sql which gives me expected results:

`select "customerUuid", array_agg("siteUuid") from "SiteCustomer" where "customerUuid" in ('id1', 'id2') group by "customerUuid";`

but when I use `typeorm`, it always returns empty array:

```
     queryRunner.manager.getRepository(SiteCustomer).
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .select('"customerUuid", array_agg("siteUuid")')
          .where('"customerUuid" IN (:customerUuids)', { customerUuids: customerUuids})
          .groupBy('"customerUuid"')
          .getMany();
```

how can I make `typeorm` work with `array_agg` in postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
      let baseQuery = queryRunner.manager.getRepository(SiteCustomer)
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select([
            '"customerUuid" as "customerUuid"',
            // It's better to specify an alias explicitly, because the default one 
            // is implicit and may be unexpected
            'array_agg("siteUuid") as "aggregatedSiteUuids"', 
      ])
      .where('"customerUuid" IN (:customerUuids)', { customerUuids: customerUuids})
      .groupBy('"customerUuid"')
```

But use -

```
baseQuery.getRawMany()
```

in case you are not selecting entities.

Comment: If would be good to [mention](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7215) where this was copied from, especially since it's the same OP asking here and there.